# How to handle integers in bash with values larger than 2^63

Tags: bash, largenumber

It seems like bash's maximum signed integer value is 9223372036854775807 (2^63)-1.  Is there a way for bash to handle larger values than this?  I need to handle numbers up to 10000000000000000000000000001, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in bash.

```
A=10000000000000000000000000000
echo $A
10000000000000000000000000000
let A+=1
echo $A
4477988020393345025
```

**EDIT**
Thanks Benjamin W. for your comment.  Based on that I am trying the following strategy.  Are there any perceived issues with this?  Meaning, aside from some performance hit due to invoking bc, would there by complications from using bc to increment my variable?

```
A=10000000000000000000000000000
echo $A
10000000000000000000000000000
A=$(bc <<< "$A+1")
echo $A
10000000000000000000000000001
```

Also, I've tested some bash operations (greater than, less than, etc) and it seems it behaves as expected.  E.g.:

```
A=10000000000000000000000000000

echo $A
10000000000000000000000000000

[[ "$A" -gt 10000000000000000000000000000 ]] && echo "A is bigger than 10000000000000000000000000000"

A=$(bc <<< "$A+1")

echo $A
10000000000000000000000000001

[[ "$A" -gt 10000000000000000000000000000 ]] && echo "A is bigger than 10000000000000000000000000000"
A is bigger than 10000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: I'll bite - why are you using Bash to process large numbers?

Comment: Very few programming languages support integers larger than 64 bits. Python has arbitrary precision integers, try using that.

Comment: Even the gawk version I am working with does not have support for large numbers, like it would with the "-M" option.  I have all the infrastructure written in a bash script for everything except handling values this large.

Comment: bc is arbitrarily precise: `bc <<< '2^63'` returns `9223372036854775808`.

Comment: Thanks.  Python was my next stop, but I was hoping bash could support it before I resort to that.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about limits to using `-gt` with numbers larger than what Bash handles in computations; when in doubt, you can also use bc to make the comparison: `if (( $(bc <<< "$a > 5") ))` - bc prints `1` for true statements and `0` for false statements, and `(( ))` maps `1` to true, `0` to false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend using `bc` with its arbitrary precision.

Bash overflows at 2<sup>63</sup>:

```
$ A=$(( 2**63 - 1 ))
$ echo $A
9223372036854775807
$ echo $(( A+1 ))
-9223372036854775808
```

bc can handle this:

```
$ bc <<< "$A+1"
9223372036854775808
```

These numbers have to be handled with bc for everything from now on, though. Using `[[ ]]`, they don't seem to overflow, but comparison doesn't work properly:

```
$ B=$(bc <<< "$A+1")
$ echo $B
9223372036854775808
$ set -vx
$ [[ $B -gt -$A ]] && echo true
[[ $B -gt -$A ]] && echo true
+ [[ 9223372036854775808 -gt -9223372036854775807 ]]
```

And in arithmetic context `(( ))`, they overflow:

```
$ echo $(( B ))
-9223372036854775808
```

so the comparison doesn't work either:

```
$ (( B > A )) && echo true || echo false
false
```

Handling them with bc:

```
$ bc <<< "$B > $A"
1
```

and since within `(( ))` non-zero results evaluate to true and zero to false, we can use

```
$ (( $(bc <<< "$B > $A") )) && echo true
true
```