# Hex to Decimal in Bash

Tags: bash, hex, decimal

I know that we can convert hex to dec in bash using

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type a hex number"
read hexNum
echo $(( 16#$hexNum ))
```

but when I run it with `hexNum=9b4bbba36e494bcd`, it gives me `-7256500063973061683` i.e negative value, which is 2's complement.

I don't want it's 2 complement. I want output for `hexNum=9b4bbba36e494bcd` as `11190244009736489933`. As given on https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-decimal.html?x=9b4bbba36e494bcd

How can I get this output using bash? Please help!

Comment: This number overflows the signed 64-bit integer that Bash can handle; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/51884432/3266847

Comment: As Bash cannot handle that number due to the reason pointed by @BenjaminW. the simplest way I see to reach that goal in your script is using Python: `python -c 'print(int("9b4bbba36e494bcd", 16))'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the number in your example is too big. `bash` does calculations with fixed size integers. Big numbers will overflow.

`bc` supports arbitrary large numbers and can do a base conversion too. However, `bc` requires hexadecimal numbers to be written in UPPERCASE, therefore you have to convert your input first. `bash` has a built-in parameter substitution to convert to upper case:

```
hex=9b4bbba36e494bcd
echo "ibase=16; ${hex^^}" | bc
```

Comment: The uppercase builtin `^^` requires bash 4+

Comment: @kos If you want to keep using a >16 year old version of bash, try `echo "ibase=16; $(echo "$hex" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')" | bc`.

Comment: I don't want to, but MacOS X ships with bash 3 by default. So good to keep on eye on the differences when writing portable scripts for a team of other developers.

Comment: zsh function that strips any proceeding `0x` and converts hex to uppercase both as required by bc: `function hexdec() { echo "ibase=16;${${1#"0x"}:u}" | bc; }`